# What is the origin of the 2001 BIONICLE pin?

Tags: bionicle

Recently I got one of these in a lot.

[image: Picture of the front]

[Picture of the back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCz4P.jpg)

Prior to receiving it, I didn't even know it existed, and can't find any information on it on the web.

What is the origin of this 2001 BIONICLE pin? Was it sold or handed out somewhere as a promotional item? Made for and worn by LEGO employees? How would one have obtained one in 2001 (assuming that's when it was made)?

Comment: The only thing I could find was a few e-bay listings, including [this](https://www.ebay.ie/itm/RH-BIONICLE-LEGO-TECHNIC-PIN-BADGE-34981/401620219197?hash=item5d826e353d:g:TisAAOSwiCRUgmdU:rk:4:pf:0) which uses the number #34981 in the selling title, although I couldn't find anything more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is

Pin85 BIONICLE Toa

a [Patch & Pin set](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Patch_%26_Pin)

given for free with LEGO Magazine or available at LEGOLAND Parks

[Pin85 BIONICLE Toa at Bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=44690#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[Pin85 BIONICLE Toa at lego.fandom.com](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Pin85_BIONICLE_Toa)